# Python OptParser

Tags: python

I am trying to input a path using optparser in python. Unfortunately this piece of code keeps showing an error.

```
import optparse,os

parser = optparse.OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-p","--path", help = "Prints path",dest = "Input_Path", metavar = "PATH")

(opts,args) =parser.parse_args()

print os.path.isdir(opts.Input_Path)
```

Error :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/armed/Documents/Python_Test.py", line 8, in 
    print os.path.isdir(opts.Input_Path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 41, in isdir
    st = os.stat(s)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
```

Any help is much appreciated !

Comment: Are you definitely calling your script with "-p something"?

Comment: Yes I am. I am inputting it as a string but i think it gets stored as a list because when I do a for file in opts.Input_Path and print file it shows the output letter by letter for whatever I am inputting. Do you know why that is ? i just want it to print the files in the directory the path is pointing to

Comment: A string is an iterable object, just like a list. "for a in a_string" will loop through the characters of the string. Instead of the for loop just use the attribute opts.Input_Path itself.

Comment: Here's the obligatory comment that optparse has been deprecated in favor of [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied your script and ran it. Looks like you call your script in a wrong way:

```
 $ python test.py /tmp
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
     print os.path.isdir(opts.Input_Path)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/genericpath.py", line 41, in isdir
     st = os.stat(s)
 TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
```

but

```
$ python test.py --path /tmp
True
```

Answer (score 3):

That error is because `opts.Input_Path` is `None`, instead of being your path string/unicode.

Are you sure you are calling the script correctly?   You should probably put in some error checking code in any case to make sure that if a user *doesnt* put -p, the program won't just crash.

Or, change it to a positional argument to make it 'required' by optparse:
http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#what-are-positional-arguments-for

Edit: Also `optparse` is deprecated, for a new project you probably want to use [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html).

Comment: Will check it out ! Thanks :) Yes i was calling it the wrong way.

Comment: If this was the problem, you should mark one of these as an answer to let the community know : )